# is it good practice to call a method from Exception block in java?

Tags: java, exception

Is it good practice to call a method from Exception block in java?

```
catch (Exception exception) {
   cleanup();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with *good/bad practice*. Do you call `cleanup()` anywhere other than in the catch clause, if so then why repeat code when you can call a function. If not then just copy the code from `cleanup()` to the catch clause, or don't it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Usually `cleanUp` tasks are well suited for `finally block` instead of `catch block`

Comment: That depends on what your method does and what your design is. I would always be careful with methods that change some internal or global state. If you use such a method inconsistent you could encounter some strange behaviour.

Comment: Is there anything I should add to the answer in order to make it also upvote worthy, now that you reached that level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **bad** practice for two reasons:

1. Normally, **cleanup** kind of actions ... should also be executed when your code doesn't fail; right? But if you only put it into the catch ... cleanup isn't called when no exception is thrown!
2. Beyond that: the above will **not** call cleanup() for subclasses of Throwable that are not Exceptions.

So, the one and only way to do such things is to use the **finally** block in order to call methods ... that should always be called. Or, depending on the actual problem at hand, you might want to look into using try-with-resources and the AutoCloseable interface.